# Redis - is it possible to get all values from a key in performance efficient manner?

Tags: redis, addition, removeall

I evaluate Redis.io for keeping clicks/logging stream (and then saving into one file or system, i.e. aggregating logs from many servers).

While adding to redis is simple SADD http://redis.io/commands#set or LPUSH http://redis.io/commands#list

(I need to choose Set or List to have messages from one logger grouped)

However, retrieving is done only one-by-one, e.g. LPOP.

I need  one command to return all current value in a Set or List and delete them at once.
If getting all and then deleting all with 2 commands, then there is risk that some entry was added in between time.

Maybe there is better solution for [Event logging with distributed database for node.js (MongoDB?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715970/event-logging-with-distributed-database-for-node-js-mongodb) with Redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sets, try the SMEMBERS command: http://redis.io/commands/smembers
After that, you may just delete the set.

Also you may need to execute these commands in the same "transaction", so the code would like

```
MULTI
SMEMBERS yourset
DEL yourset
EXEC
```

Comment: Will MULTI EXEC block guarantee atomic execution ?

Comment: They say so, although we never relied on Redis transactions in production. You may want to read the http://redis.io/topics/transactions page, and perhaps do some tests whether it will work for you.